# Testing MobX Component

Tags: reactjs, testing, jestjs, mobx

I am facing an issue of how to test a component in Mobx that we are passing props to. 
I am using **Jest** and I just want to make a simple snapshot test.

Next to default export I am also using named export of just the component so @inject and @observer don't influence it. I should just  pass my own 'expenses' and 'filters' as a prop but it is not working.

So this is my component. I am passing RootStore as a prop to that component.

**ExpenseList Component**

```
 @inject('RootStore')
    @observer
    export class ExpenseList extends Component {
      render() {
        const {expenses} = this.props.RootStore.ExpensesStore
        const {filters} = this.props.RootStore.FiltersStore
        const expensesFilter = selectExpense(expenses, filters)
        return (
          <div>
          {
            expenses.length === 0 ? (
              <p>No expenses</p>
            ) : (
              expensesFilter.map((expense) => {
                return <ExpenseListItem key={expense.id} {...expense} />
              })
            )
          }
          </div>
        )
      }
    }
```

**ExpenseList.test.js**

```
import React from 'react'
import { shallow } from 'enzyme'
import { ExpenseList } from '../../components/ExpenseList'
import expenses from '../fixtures/expenses'

test('should render ExpenseList with expenses', () => {
  // const wrapper = shallow(<ExpenseList RootStore={{'ExpensesStore':{'expenses':expenses}}}/>)
  const wrapper = shallow(<ExpenseList 
  RootStore={
    {
      'ExpensesStore':{
        'expenses':expenses
      },
      'FiltersStore': {
        'filters': {
          text: 'e',
          sortBy: 'date',
          startDate: '11.2017.',
          endDate: '12.2017.'
        }

      }
    }
  }
  />)
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```

This is my **RootStore**

```
import ExpensesStore from './ExpensesStore'
import FiltersStore from './FiltersStore'

class RootStore {
    ExpensesStore = new ExpensesStore(this)
    FiltersStore = new FiltersStore(this)
}

const rootStore = new RootStore()

export default rootStore
```

**ExpensesStore**

```
class ExpensesStore {

  constructor(rootStore) {
    this.rootStore = rootStore
  }

  @observable expenses = [];

  findExpense(paramsId) {
    return computed(() => {
      return this.expenses.find((expense) => expense.id === paramsId)
    }).get()
  }

}

export default ExpensesStore
```

**FiltersStore**

```
class FiltersStore {

  constructor(rootStore) {
    this.rootStore = rootStore
  }

  @observable filters = {
    text: '',
    sortBy: 'date',
    startDate: moment().startOf('month'),
    endDate: moment().endOf('month')
  }

}

export default FiltersStore
```

Comment: I don't see a `<Provider>` anywhere in your code that would make the `RootStore` available to your `ExpenseList` component.

Comment: I figured it out. The problem were decorators.

Comment: How to test only data FiltersStore or ExpensesStore??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok. The problem were decorators at the top of the component.

Using shallow rendering won't provide any useful results when testing injected components; only the injector will be rendered. To test with shallow rendering, instantiate the wrappedComponent

```
test('should render ExpenseList with expenses', () => {
  const wrapper = shallow(<ExpenseList.wrappedComponent 
  RootStore = {
    {
      ExpensesStore: {
        expenses
      },
      FiltersStore: {
        filters: {
          text: 'e',
          sortBy: 'date',
          startDate: '',
          endDate: ''
        }
      }
    }
  } 
  />)
  expect(wrapper).toMatchSnapshot();
})
```